# Fetching data from PLIST by Fast Enumeration

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, for-in-loop

I am using  `for in` loop to fetch data from plist.`For in` loop is correct as it is printing value. But,suddenly, it is showing following **exception**:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x97a14b0'.
```

**Code:**

```
   NSString *sss=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"s" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSDictionary *dic=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:sss];

    for(NSArray *arr in [dic allKeys])
    {

    NSLog(@"%@",arr); // Ii is printing value

    NSLog(@"%@",arr[0]); // It is showing exceptions
    }
```

**Plist:**

[image]

There is some problem with         `NSLog(@"%@",arr[0]);`. I want to print values of first index of arrays `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here `[dic allKeys]` will be keys in `dic` that are `NSString` like "a", "b" etc.

so for your plist the code should be,

```
NSString *sss=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"s" ofType:@"plist"];

NSDictionary *dic=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:sss];

for(NSString *key in [dic allKeys])
{

     NSLog(@"%@",key); 
     NSArray *value = [dic objectForKey:key];
     NSLog(@"%@",value[0]); 
}
```

Comment: My code is also working. Only change I have made is `for(NSArray *arr in [dic allValues])`.

Comment: yes, you can do in that way too. i have seen a log for `NSLog(@"%@",arr);` so thought you need to log(or require) the key too.